# Malformed Info.plist causes macOS crash

Tags: xcode, macos, crash

By accident, I added the line <array></array> to my applications' Contents/Info.plist file. When launching the app in the Xcode debugger, the computer appears to crash and reboot. Is this considered a security relevant issue?

Steps to reproduce on macOS Sierra 10.12.6 and Xcode 8.3.3:

(1) create and build a default Cocoa App in Xcode

(2) using a text editor, add the line <array></array> to the end of the <plist> block in your <app>/Contents/Info.plist; here are the last 3 lines of my Info.plist:

</dict>
<array></array>
</plist>

(3) do not build but just run the app in the Xcode debugger; the app crashes, a gray screen appears and your machine reboots

Comment: I just want to stress, in step (3) use "Run Without Building", so the Info.plist does not get overwritten by a new compile.

Comment: I double checked with High Sierra and it too crashes. Here is a simpler scenario: (1) duplicate TextEdit.app (2) use vi to edit Info.plist and add &ltarray&gt&lt/array&gt like above (3) double click TextEdit copy.app (5) dialog appears, click Open (6) enjoy the crash

Answer (score 0):

I have a feeling that something else is going on here. You are one major OS version behind (two if you could betas), and I have a feeling that if you were to open a bug with Apple, they'll just tell you to install the latest stuff. But I have the latest, so I'll try.

I'm running 10.14, and I tried what you suggested. I went in and manually disabled code-signing, which is required with Xcode 10 (and 9 think). When I follow your tests, the app just fails to launch. launchd produces an error to the effect of "Invalid property list".

So, could this be a bug in an older OS, for sure. And why not open a bug with Apple. Just include what you have here. But, I suspect that something else is up on your machine, which triggers the panic. You might be able to dig into logs to figure that out.

**update**

I followed the instructions to just modify TextEdit.app, and insert the `<array><\array>`. I was able to reproduce the panic on 10.13, but not on 10.11 or 10.14 (the only machines I have handy).

```
*** Panic Report ***
panic(cpu 0 caller 0xffffff8012515e80):  initproc exited -- exit reason namespace 2 subcode 0x4 description: none
```

I'm fairly sure this means that launchd crashed. I believe that when that happens, the kernel just panics. Interestingly, I tried a modification that invalidates the signature but **does not** make the Info.plist invalid. Those seem to not causes the panic. That just does what all the other OSes do, which is cause the process to crash with:

```
Application Specific Information:
dyld: launch, running initializers
/usr/lib/libSystem.B.dylib
Sandbox registration failed: The code signature is not valid: The operation couldn’t be completed. (OSStatus error -67030.)
```

That's exactly what I *would* have expected on 10.13. And I was able to make it happen in certain circumstances. But, not with this specific change.

Comment: High Sierra 10.13.6 crashes too. Try my example using a copy of TextEdit.app. Insert the line in xml notation (I'm having trouble to enter that here, xml gets erased in posts). See initial post. It really crashes MacOSX.

Comment: Does not happen for me on 10.14 beta 3. I get the (expected) "Sandbox registration failed: The code signature is not valid: The operation couldn’t be completed". I'm unsure how to turn off code signing for 10.14. I'm going to try with a 10.13 machine too.

Comment: Also just tried on a 10.11 machine I had handy. App won't open, produces lots of logging about being unable to parse the plist, but also no panic.

Comment: Forget about using Xcode to create an app. Just duplicate TextEdit.app and edit the Info.plist. Make sure the only thing you add is that one line defining an empty array at the right spot as described above. Use a simple editor like vi, nano, emacs to edit the XML. So far I tried on 4 different Macs and each crashed and rebooted.

Comment: I tried to follow your TextEdit.app example exactly as you described it. Didn't cause a panic for me. Apple code signs their own apps too, so as soon as you modify the contents of the bundle, the validation fails and it refuses to load. How are you getting around that? Also, have you checked the machines for the panic log? It would be interesting to see what's actually happening.

Comment: *** Panic Report ***
panic(cpu 2 caller 0xffffff800616a63f): initproc exited  -- exit reason namespace 2 subcode 0x4 description: none

uuid info:
 0x11aa09000 uuid = <322c06b7-8878-311d-888c-c8fd2ca96ff3>
 0x10ea86000 uuid = <7dff49fe-e473-3881-a928-ef960f24b327>

Thread 2 crashed

RAX: 0x00007fff8d5e03c4, RBX: 0x000070000ab83bc0, RCX: 0x000070000ab83bf2, RDX: 0x000070000ab83558

Comment: When you double click the modified "TextEdit copy.app", what happens? Do you get a confirmation dialog allowing you to "Open" the app? Did you try again with < 10.14?

Comment: Ok, so yes - I updated my answer. I was able to make it happen with 10.13, but only 10.13, and only with that exact change. Definitely worth reporting, even though it doesn't seem to happen on 10.14 now.